# Is it possible to generate an S3 download URL without query parameters?

Tags: amazon-s3, ipxe, radosgw

I am using an S3 instance provided by the Ceph Rados Gateway, not Amazon S3.

I can generate download urls like this:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<bucket>/<key>?AWSAccessKeyId=<access_key>&Signature=<signature>&Expires=<expires>
```

but certain clients, like iPXE don't seem to be able to handle downloading from an HTTP source that contains query parameters. I don't really care what the format of the url is, just so long as it can be downloaded by picky clients.

Is this even possible?

Comment: This appears to be possible only with extra software (e.g. a reverse proxy that can modify requests in flight) and maybe more hardware (to run that).  Your best strategy is probably to try to understand what's causing the failure and try to solve or work around it.  Is there a way to capture the errors?  Wireshark, if all else fails.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, I have a lot of digging to do with iPXE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up being able to make this work by using the iPXE `imgfetch`/`initrd`/`module` commands. They allow you to take whatever you have downloaded and rename the downloaded file to something that is capable of being saved.

Link: [docs](http://ipxe.org/cmd/imgfetch)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the object to public read permission, so that's it.

Comment: All of my objects in my bucket are already public read permission.